# How to I make php make text on a new line in a text file

Tags: php, file, text, ip, newline

My current php file looks like

```
    <?php
$ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org');
echo "Your IP address is: " . $ip;
file_put_contents ('date.txt'), $ip);

?>
```

This makes a text file called data.txt and in it has my IP.
But each time this php files is ran it replaces the ip in txt file
I would like it to not replace it but instead add a new ip to another line

data.txt (currently)

```
83.169.130.59 <---- This is what gets replaced
```

I would like it to make it so it adds another ip underneath the other one like this:

```
83.169.130.59
81.214.214.15
21.251.214.14
192.125.144.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `FILE_APPEND` as third argument in `file_put_contents()` function, like this:

```
file_put_contents('date.txt', $ip . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND)
```

Here's the reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: I get `83.169.130.5983.169.130.5983.169.130.5983.169.130.5983.169.130.5983.169.130.5983.169.130.5983.169.130.5983.169.130.59` I would like it to go in a list is this possible. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadAli I've updated my answer. Please see the updated code snippet.